# How to set email to a user in Active Directory programatically using c#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have programatically created a user in Active Directory. I want to set that user's email. I used the following code to set email address in active directory:

```
UserDirectoryEntry.Properties["mail"].Value = "john@gmail.com";
UserDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();
```

At this point, the email address gets set in active directory properly. But the moment, i try to update another property for that user say for eg:

```
UserDirectoryEntry.Properties["telephoneNumber"].value = "022-2345678";
UserDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();
```

After this point, the email address that we set earlier to "mail" field gets replaced with SamAccountName@domainName.com.

Can you please tell me why the email address is getting replaced with SamAccountName@domainName.com even if i have set it to "john@gmail.com".
I m using APIs of Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this works for you, but you can try adding the email instead of setting it:

```
UserDirectoryEntry.Properties["mail"].Add("john@gmail.com");
```

You will be still able to find the user bu this email.